# Ion engine: purpose of magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, propulsion

I have a question about the gridded electrostatic ion engine.
In the ionisation chamber there are several magnet rings that create a magnetic field inside the chamber. [image: gridded electrostatic ion engine]

But what is the purpose of that magnetic field?

Comment: My guess is it's to make the ion beam to move more in a particular direction and less in the full half-sphere behind the ship.

Answer (score 1):

As the picture says, they are to increase the ionization efficiency. They are not used to direct the discharged exhaust.

Electrons are injected into the ionization chamber so that they can interact with neutral Xenon, knocking off more valence electrons and turning the Xenon into positive ions. We want to increase the likelihood that this interaction will happen. The magnetic fields help make this happen by better confining the electrons.

Go to the beginning of chapter 3 (page 91) in [this](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/SciTechBook/series1/Goebel__cmprsd_opt.pdf) book for more info.